# Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: java, spring-boot, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to hit my local server (https://localhost:8443/somefucn) from an Outlook Addin, I am getting the following error : "
[Error] Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “localhost”, which could put your confidential information at risk. (secured, line 0)"

Can you please help me with some solution or leads to resolve this.

Comment: are you able to open URL on browser without any issue/warning

Comment: Did you generate and self sign the certificate yourself? If so, what did you use as the CN and the Subject Alternative Names ? You can view the certificate in a browser by navigaging to https://localhost:8443 and clicking the padlock next to https in the nav bar..